# How does the EDIT ALL button works in quotelineitem object

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-button, quote

Can any one help me out.How does the EDIT ALL button works in quotelineitem object .When we click on the "EDIT ALL" button it gives the available records present to Edit and Save.Im in a similar requirement where i would like to create a Button for a custom object on a related list.When an User clicks the button ,it should give the available records present in the custom object to Edit and Save .Has any one tried on this type of sceanrio.I shall appreciate your help.Any Suggestion Plz.

Comment: See also http://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf page 59 for a no-APEX solution - (caveat - user needs to click check boxes for rows they want to massedit). Also, nikkey, I notice you post a lot of VF questions on SFSE - you should consider investing in https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/visualforce-development-cookbook - well worth the $ as it is chock-o-block with recipes for VF use cases

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth looking at this recipe on michaelforce: http://www.michaelforce.org/recipeView?id=a0G30000006eVxVEAU

It's a replacement for the Opportunity Product Edit All screen so could give you a starting point on how to develop a Edit All screen. It's well commented and easy to follow.